# Apache Ignite update eviction policy (time) of already started cache

Tags: ignite, policy

Does Apache Ignite allow to update eviction policy (time) of already started cache?

We have an implemenation in our system where we store data in Ignite cache. But we need to be able to update eviction time on existing cache without losing data in the cache. Creating a new cache is not an option in our case.

Answer (score 2):

Changing the configured default is not possible; it's part of the configuration.

But, you can always create a new cache wrapper with the required policy. From the [docs](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/configuring-caches/expiry-policies#configuration):

```
CacheConfiguration<Integer, String> cacheCfg = new CacheConfiguration<Integer, String>("myCache");

ignite.createCache(cacheCfg);

IgniteCache cache = ignite.cache("myCache")
        .withExpiryPolicy(new CreatedExpiryPolicy(new Duration(TimeUnit.MINUTES, 5)));

// if the cache does not contain key 1, the entry will expire after 5 minutes
cache.put(1, "first value");

IgniteCache cache2 = ignite.cache("myCache")
        .withExpiryPolicy(new CreatedExpiryPolicy(new Duration(TimeUnit.MINUTES, 2)));

// if the cache does not contain key 2, the entry will expire after 2 minutes
cache2.put(2, "second value");
```